# Stream Zend Framework Not Found

Tags: zend-framework

Hello I have error message

> Message: Class 'Zend\Log\Writer\Stream' not found

I tried install `zend framework` but same error, any idea for this case?

Comment: Did you installed `zend-log` library? If not, run `composer require zendframework/zend-log` in your project.

Comment: Yeah but it can't be installed with message "package zend framework/zendstdlib is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-stdlib instead." and other package like zend-container interop, zend-servicemanager, and zend-log

Comment: Well, the message is speaking by itself :) Install `laminas/laminas-log`, and use `Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream` instead of `Zend\Log\Writer\Stream`. Take a look at the [zend-log](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-log/) and [laminas-log](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-log/) docs